# Android: get xml file in TypedArray in custom view

Tags: android, android-custom-view

I am creating a custom view so to set it's attribute i create attrs.xml:

```
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name="ShapedView">
        <attr name="src" format="reference"/>
        <attr name="model_crop" format="reference"/>
        <attr name="model_crop_string" format="string"/>
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

Now i create a simple xml vector in drawable folder:

simple_vector.xml

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="400px"
    android:height="400px"
    android:viewportHeight="400.0"
    android:viewportWidth="400.0" >
        <path
            android:fillColor="#0000FF"
            android:strokeColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:strokeWidth="4"
            android:pathData="M100,100 L 300,100 L 200,300z" />
</vector>
```

and i use this attrs:

```
private void initView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    TypedArray typedArray = context.getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(
            attrs, R.styleable.ShapedView, 0, 0);
    model_crop = typedArray.getDrawable(R.styleable.ShapedView_model_crop);
    /// get xml 
}
```

I want to get simple_vector.xml as a xml file to parse it. How could i get xml file or inputStream as a TypedArray ?
Mainlayout.xml:

```
<com.imageviewcustom.ShapedImageView
    android:layout_width="400dp"
    android:layout_height="400dp"
    app:model_crop="@drawable/simple_vector"
    app:model_crop_string="@string/crop_string"
    app:src="@drawable/image" />
```

That's mean i want to get `model_crop` as a inputStream or file in custom view?

Comment: check `TypedArray` documentation - it has several `get*` methods

Comment: I do not have `documentation reference`! @pskink

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/TypedArray

Comment: dude where is documentation? http://pasteall.org/pic/show.php?id=b1bac254c286e729d4c7cfe8f49439df   @pskink

Comment: here is `TypedArray` documentation: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/TypedArray

Comment: Dude i am confused, what `get` i have to use? because i do not see any `get` with `documentation`? do you mean `getResources()` ? @pskink

Comment: check all `TypedArray#get*` methods - `TypedArray` has for example `getFloat`  for obtaining float value, `getInt` for int value and there is another `get` method for obtaining `@drawable/simple_vector` resource identifier

Comment: vector.xml is just a drawable, and in Android we got VectorDrawable class, so just use ```ta.getDrawable(R.styleable.ShapedView_model_vector)``` and type cast to VectorDrawable ,  to use vector https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/vector-drawable-resources

Comment: and even if its not working then just put in raw folder and access the file by R.raw.vector. you will get the inputstream you can convert into in string(XML)

Comment: There's no need to keep a separate copy in `raw/`. If you really want to parse drawable XML yourself, then use `TypedArray#getResourceId()` to get the ID, like pskink alluded to. Then use `getResources().getXml()` with that ID to get an `XmlResourceParser`. You can't get a `File`, since it's not a file anymore after building, and I'm not aware of any drawable resource method that returns an `InputStream`, so the `XmlResourceParser` is probably the best you can do, though that's likely the best fit, anyway.

Comment: @MikeM. `Resources#openRawResource` - the name is misleading but they say that: *"Open a data stream for reading a raw resource. This can only be used with resources whose value is the name of an asset file -- that is, it can be used to open drawable, sound, and raw resources; it will fail on string and color resources."*

Comment: @pskink Ah, yeah, I kinda forgot about `openRawResource()`, but I did specify "_drawable_ resource method". ;-) However, the `XmlResourceParser` would be the easiest to use for this, IMO, anyway.

Comment: @MikeM. oh, sorry, i missed "drawable resource method" :-)

Comment: @pskink I win, on a technicality! \o/ On a serious note, though, that `InputStream` is just gonna be the raw binary format that all XML gets processed into, isn't it? I seem to recall playing around with that method when I was doing a resource extractor thingy.

Comment: @MikeM. i think that `InputStream` would make the same effect (when passed to [setInput](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser.html#setInput(java.io.InputStream,%20java.lang.String)) method) as using `Resources#getXml()` method directly, so the latter is the better option

Comment: @pskink Hmm, I'm not so sure about that. I'm thinking that's only going to accept plaintext, whatever the encoding might be. Also, the framework uses [a pretty specialized parser implementation for compiled XML](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/content/res/XmlBlock.java#84), with a bunch of native calls. Anyhoo, it's not a big deal. Academic, really. I think the OP has enough information, now, to get up and running, whatever they're actually trying to do. Cheers!

Comment: I write `int model_crop_id = typedArray.getResourceId(R.styleable.ShapedView_model_crop,-1);` and then `XmlResourceParser xml = getResources().getXml(model_crop_id);` but when i write `xml.getText()` i get null @MikeM.

Comment: http://pasteall.org/pic/show.php?id=336e388381804d462c3ea7be4050dd34 @MikeM.

Comment: Yeah, that's not how to use that parser. You need to set up a loop, looking for specific event types, and tag and attribute names. You might have a look at the  "minimal example" shown on the [`XmlPullParser` docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser.html).